# In opencv is there a way to open an .avi that is being recorded and created real time?

Tags: windows, opencv, image-processing, video, avi

I have a camera recording app that takes in a camera image and records and saves the camera image output as an .avi file that I can play and do whatever once done recording. I want to create a real time opencv code that can take these .avi file that is being created real time, open it, manipulate it do some classification real time. Is there anyway for opencv to open these .avi as they are being written? preferably python but also C++ implementation? This will be done on windows10.

edit:
Currently when I try to do the generic video capture the with the output .avi with CV2 as

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('out.avi')
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video_grab.py", line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion 
failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

where the assertion fail most likely since the video has 0 by 0 dimension while the capture is stopped and saved.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution may work or not, depending on the codec of the AVI file:

- Verify that `ret` value is `True`.
- Increase the time in `waitKey` to something larger than 1msec.

```python
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('out.avi')

frame_period = 100  # 100msec - assume frame rate is about 10Hz

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(frame_period) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I testes it using "Motion JPEG" codec, and I am getting a warning message like: `[mjpeg @ 000002a22394b0e0] overread 8`, when reading in faster rate than actual frame rate.

You may also try, start reading fast, and reduce the rate when `ret = False`:

```python
frame_period = 1  # Start reading fast (wait only 1msec)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    else:
        frame_period = 100 # Reduce the rate to 10Hz when reaching end of file.  

    if cv2.waitKey(frame_period) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I think it's going to work better if you have some indication that new frame was captured.
I couldn't find a solution for that by just "querying" the AVI file using OpenCV.